# Using the Weather Underground API for retrieving weather info

Tags: java, weather

First of all, is it possible to use the API in a Java application ? The code examples *do not* list Java.

Anyways, I was wondering if it was possible to combine GeoIP geolocation and Weather Underground in a stand-alone Java application to retrieve weather data.

The URL to be constructed looks like this:
`http://api.wunderground.com/api/[API key here]/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json`

So can I use the `URLConnection` class to get the information of the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- 
Yes you should be able to call it from a `Java` application and parse the `json` response

2- You can specify the country/city in your query as following:

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/Your_Key/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/Country/City.json
```

Comment: I tried `India` for country and `Delhi` for city and I got a **key does not exist** response. I even tried the latitude / longitude pair. No luck.

Comment: Worked. There was a typo :) How do I parse the response? I found one [resource here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/)

Comment: @LittleChild You could simply read in the response and manually parse it (take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [here](http://www.json.org/) for format) or you could take advantage of a 3rd party library like [Google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)